# Can I generate a QR code for a contact?

Tags: contacts, qr-code, vcard

I'm pretty sure I remember someone showing me a tool they were using to generate QR codes for individual contacts on their Android.

How do I generate a QR code for a contact?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the popular [Barcode Scanner](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android&feature=search_result) App, it gives you a "share via barcode" option in the "share" menu when viewing a contact.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung contacts app as of 2021 has a "share as QR" option which generates a QR with the contact vCard and the picture of the contact in the middle.