# Open Source "My QR code" app to quickly share my contact details?

Tags: contacts, open-source, qr-code

Especially in Japan/Korea, there are many proprietary apps to quickly share your name+email+phone. Example [here](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.keylife.addressqr_19_22). They all work the same way:

- At first use, enter your name, email, phone: It generates "your" QR code.
- Whenever you meet someone and want to keep in touch:

  - Launch the app, it instantly shows your QR code
  - The other person scans it, and can add you as a contact without typing anything.

Key features:

- Extremely fast, should take less time than a web page load.
- Fit to screen size for easier scanning, maybe even make the screen brighter temporarily.
- Options to show a different QR code for carriers that use a special format.

**QUESTION: Is there an Open Source app that does this?**
*If not, I might create one, but I prefer to ask first.*
*Almost nobody uses [Bump](http://bu.mp/faq) here in Japan, making it pointless.*

Comment: Looks like you need [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10303/can-i-generate-a-qr-code-for-a-contact). Barcode Scanner already does this, and is quite handy. It's [open source too](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions). From what I can see, shared details are name, company, company address, email(s) and phone number(s).

Comment: @MartinTapankov: Yes, it is theoretically doable, but: 1) Far too slow, requires 5 touches even though I have a shortcut to my own contact entry on the desktop. 2) Shares too many details, including my physical address, which belong to the contacts but should not be shared. 3) Might not be readable from all carriers, especially on non-smartphones.

Comment: In that case, why not just create a QR image for yourself that has all the contact information you want, and make a shortcut on the home screen?

Comment: @MartinTapankov: good idea for me, for the average user  it is too technical though. That's why there are tons of apps that do it for you. Now I was just wondering if there is an Open Source one.